# How do I add a custom list view for pre populate SQLite data list?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

The list view is working.But I want to add a custom list view for this data list. I'm retrieving data from a pre populate data base. This is what I tried. I'm getting an error in activity class.

CustomListViewAdapter

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Organization> {

Context context;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int layout,
                             List<Organization> items) {
    super(context, layout, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {

    TextView txtTitle;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Organization rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.org_name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());


    return convertView;
}}
```

Bean Class

```
public class Organization {

    private String title;


    public Organization(String title) {

        this.title = title;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }    }
```

Activity class

```
public class ContactView extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ListView listView1;
    List<Organization> rowItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);


    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    DBAccess databaseAccess = DBAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes(getIntent().getStringExtra("ID_EXTRA"));
    databaseAccess.close();


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.single_row_item, quotes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

Error I'm getting

```
Error:(81, 41) error: constructor CustomListViewAdapter in class CustomListViewAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
```

required: Context,int,List
found: ContactView,int,List
reason: actual argument List cannot be converted to List by method invocation conversion

Comment: What error are you getting? And why are you initializing your listView 2 times inside the Activity? Remove one of the initialization.

Comment: I added error I'm getting. Removed one initialization. Thank you

Comment: Because you are passing List<string> and CustomListViewAdapter expecting List<Organization >

Comment: I changed it as List<Organization> quotes. Now I'm getting an error on that line.

Comment: do not use any `CustomListViewAdapter`, use `[Simple]CursorAdapter` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes after `databaseAccess.close();`

```
List<Organization> rowItem=new ArrayList<Organization>();
for(String quote:quotes){
    Organization temp=new Organization(quote);
    rowItem.add(temp);
}
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
        R.layout.single_row_item, rowItem);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem with your current code is that constructor for `CustomListViewAdapter` is expecting third argument as `List` of type `Organization` but you are passing `List` of type `String`.